# Не объявляется массив в скобках

Tags: c++, массивы

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, l, r, k;
    int count;
    cin >> n >> l >> r >> k;
    count = n;
    int n_d[101];
    //Заполнение массива
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        n_d[i] = 2;
    }
    //Первый круг
    for(int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
    {
        //-------
        for(int t = 0; t < n; t++)
        {
            n_d[t] = 2;
        }
        //-------
        if(k - n_d[t] < 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        if(k - n_d[t] == 0)
        {
            cout << count;
        }
        if(k - n_d[t] > 0)
        {
            k = k - n_d[t];
        }
    }
    cout << k;
}
```

Пишет : error: 't' was not declared in this scope что делать, не могу понять?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`t` объявлена в заголовке цикла `for`, а значит, видна только в теле этого цикла.

Но она у вас все равно по выходе из цикла *была бы* равна `n`, так какой смысл в проверке

```
    if(k - n_d[t] < 0)
```

? проверяйте просто

```
    if(k - n_d[n] < 0)
```

Если это, конечно, то, что вы хотели (в чем я сомневаюсь...)